# Wordpress Userroles button getting cached

Tags: cache, plugin-w3-total-cache

I am having different buttons for different users in my site, i have used the below code to create those.

```
<?php 
    global $user_login, $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);
    $roles = array (
        'administrator',
        'daily',
        'monthly',
        'unlimited',

    );
    $roles_expired = array (
        'expired',
    );
if (is_user_logged_in() && array_intersect( $roles, $user_info->roles)) {
echo Button 1; 
} else if (is_user_logged_in() && array_intersect( $roles_expired, $user_info->roles)) {

    echo 'Button2';
}
else {

  echo 'Button3';
}
?>
```

The code is working for me, but when i enable caching(using w3-total-cache) in the website the button 
is also cached for different user roles also?

is there a better way to implement this ?
Please help me

Thanks and Regards
Anand RK

Answer (score 0):

If this is on a specific page you'll be able to exclude the page from being cached under Performance > Page Cache > Advanced.

If it's on every page you'll have to enable fragment caching. Set the method to Disk: Basic and enable Late Initialization in Performance > Page Cache > Advanced. Set the following constant in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY', md5( rand( 0, 999999 ) ) );
```

Then wrap any sections you don't want cached like so:

```
<!--mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->

<?php // your dynamic button code here ?>

<!--/mfunc <?php echo W3TC_DYNAMIC_SECURITY; ?> -->
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, Is there any other method, beacuse, when i started using cloudflare, there also the same problem came,

Comment: I know you can bypass the whole page with Cloudflare using Page Rules, but I'm not aware of a way to bypass them with dynamic fragments.